# Angular Material datepicker does not return value when action button is in use

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

1. The problem is that when clicking today-button, it is working, but when changing the date in datepicker, nothing happens and this seems to be because action button is in use. How today-button is doable without action button?
2. If I add touchUi mode true, today-button disappears.

   ```
    <mat-form-field class="toolbar-button-calendar-picker">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" #selDate (dateInput)="onDateChange($event.value)">
      <mat-datepicker class="date-picker" touchUi #picker>
        <mat-datepicker-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
              (click)="clickToDay.emit()"
              matDatepickerApply>
              {{ "today" | translate }}
            </button>
          </mat-datepicker-actions>
      </mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this. For anyone in the future / if you are still having this problem, here is a potential solution:

When you add mat-datepicker-actions it seems that it it turns off the automatic selection & update when you pick a date.

I didn't want to have to spend too much time figuring it out, so the easiest solution for me was to just add cancel and apply buttons. Kind of a hack, but it works.

```
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (dateChange)="onDateChange(event.value)" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker>
    <mat-datepicker-actions>
      <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="goToday()">Today</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
    </mat-datepicker-actions>
  </mat-datepicker>
```